# Backward negativity in regex (php)

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm using regex with PHP's preg_replace when processing user input to make hyperlinks come to life using this piece of code:

```
preg_replace(
   '!(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i',
   '<a class="external" href="$1">$1</a>',
   $text
);
```

What I need to do, however, is to ignore all links encased in `{{ }}`, so for example, this input should be processed by regex:

`http://www.example.com/`

This input should be ignored:

`{{http://www.example.com/}}`

How can I change my regex pattern to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround your regex with a negative lookbehind (`(?<!...)`) and a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`):

```
'/(?<!\{\{)(((f|ht)tp:\/\/)[-a-zа-я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;\/=]+)(?!\}\})/i'
```

Alternatively, just go through the text word by word, and try and see if a word is a valid URL using a URL parsing library (you cannot have a space in a URL); and replace only in this case.

Comment: So what is the complete line of code? Do I start with ``!`` ?

Comment: @fge: In cases like these, it is almost _always_ easier to match what you don't want to match, and then, through alternation, match the rest. Okay, that might sound weird. Let me explain with some pseudo-regex: `/{{links}}|(links)//`. See what I mean? By doing this, you avoid 100% of the issues you'll have with using lookarounds like you are.

Comment: @RiMMER see edit. Also, you can simplify your character classes: no need for `A-Z` and `А-Я` in it since you ignore case

Comment: @Lindrian yes, I know, but in these cases usually I don't use regexes at all. Java has the very practical `URI` class which can validate that kind of stuff for me.

Comment: PHP Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 3

Comment: @RiMMER then replace '!' with another delimiter, or just go with a URL validation library... Which you should do, really. It will be _much_ easier and less error prone.

Comment: What does a URL validation library has to do with replacing user text to make links come alive?

Comment: Very simple: if you try and validate the URL and it fails, it means this is not a URL and therefore you don't have to do the replacement!

Comment: But my input is not a URL, my input is a huge piece of text (an article, for example).

Comment: Yes, which is why, if you read the answer, I told you to split the text word by word and test for a valid URL for each word.

Comment: That could work too, however I'm not testing only for URLs. I want to replace {{URL}} to <img>, while URL to <a>. But the word-by-word split could work I guess ..

Comment: @fge, you need to change the delimiter in your answer, too.  You can't use a character as a delimiter if you're using it as a metacharacter in the regex.  (Except for bracketing characters like `{}` and `<>`, but you have to make sure they're properly balanced within the regex.)

Comment: @AlanMoore: Well, his code doesn't work at all, seems like it ... :/

Comment: @RiMMER because of the delimiter problem just mentioned... I just used / instead.